# ACF doesn't show fields when page is translated with WPML in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wpml

I'm using ACF (Advance Custom Field) for custom fields and I translated my page in two languages. Before translating the page, fields are displayed well, but now when I translate the page, fields doesn't shown. Those fields are created for Pages (not for Posts).

I used `<?php the_field('field_name'); ?>` to get the field, but this doesn't work. I tried with specific ID like this: `<?php the_field('field_name', 1522); ?>` and it worked, but I think that if user will delete this page, this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Just ran into this! You have may have to prefix the field name with the language code e.g. `en_field_name` or `es_field_name`

Comment: Have you followed the instructions listed here (specifically enabling field group translation in WPML -> Translation Management): https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/multilingual-custom-fields/